# E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is ros-kinetic-desktop-full available? I have followed the steps from http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu but keep getting the error `E: Unable to locate package ors-kinetic-desktop-full` when I enter `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full`

Also if I try to click on the link given on the installation page where it says "or click here" the link fails.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235397/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-kinetic-desktop-full/) by [dolphin123](https://answers.ros.org/users/26999/dolphin123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-27**:
It should be available, yes. See [status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=desktop](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=desktop). That is for x86/64 though, and you don't tell us your architecture / platform.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-27**:
@dolphin123, did Step 1.2 succeed? Did you do `sudo apt-get update` as instructed in Step 1.4? Also, keep in mind that "ROS Kinetic ONLY supports Wily (Ubuntu 15.10), Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) and Jessie (Debian 8) for debian packages."

**Comment by [dolphin123](https://answers.ros.org/users/26999/dolphin123/) on 2016-05-27**:
I am using a 64-bit PC with Ubuntu 16.04. Step 1.2 succeeded and I updated, but I still get the error above that the kinetic desktop full package cannot be located.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-27**:
Does `apt-cache search ros-kinetic` find anything at all?

**Comment by [rospiguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28001/rospiguy/) on 2016-09-27**:
In my case `apt-cache search ros-kinetic` produced a long list which included ros-kinetic-desktop but not ros-kinetic-desktop-full which apparently is not included in the download from http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu. Installing per the second option in step 1.4 worked fine.

**Comment by [yuxwind](https://answers.ros.org/users/35447/yuxwind/) on 2018-05-24**:
As my platform is Ubuntu Trusty(14.04), only Indigo Igloo and Jade Turtle work for me. When I tried to install  ros-kinetic-desktop-full, it reported the error as yours.

The complete list of target platform and ros version is at http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#jade-turtle-may-2015-may-2017.

**Comment by [babayaga](https://answers.ros.org/users/40457/babayaga/) on 2019-03-13**:
I tried installing ROS and got the same error
running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.
I tried everything mentioned here , but it ain't working

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"E: Unable to locate package ***ors***-kinetic-desktop-full", didn't you just mistype 'ros'?

---

Originally posted by [JamesWell](https://answers.ros.org/users/26363/jameswell/) with karma: 136 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kc2](https://answers.ros.org/users/27726/kc2/) on 2016-08-10**:
Hi,my source list is fine but still got error on a pi 3:
When "sudo apt-get update", it hit packages.ros.org jessie InRelease, and jessie/main armhf Packages, etc.
But "apt-cache search ros-kinetic" gave error; or even "ros" returned nothing.
I could install from src, but wonder if I did wrong. thks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar issue, the problem for me was that I did not run apt-get update after setting up the ros sources.list and keys.

running sudo apt-get update after setting up the sources and keys downloaded the following packages:

```
Get:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease [4,025 B]
Get:9 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main armhf Packages [245 kB]
```

Running the following install command after that worked fine:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

---

Originally posted by [Lex](https://answers.ros.org/users/28983/lex/) with karma: 51 on 2017-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haifei](https://answers.ros.org/users/23965/haifei/) on 2017-12-31**:
Thanks a lot! this works, following steps in http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu.